# Search and Pagination Laravel 4

Tags: php, search, laravel, pagination

I have a problem, I want to use the form to do a search and use pagination. The problem is when I change the page, an error occurs:

No query results for model [Aluno].

My controller

```
Route::post(
'alunos/busca', 
array(
    'as' => 'alunos.busca', 
    'uses' => 'AlunosController@busca'
)
```

);

My Controller

```
public function busca()
{
   $search = Input::get('q');
   $alunos = Aluno::where('curso', $search)->paginate(1);
   return View::make('alunos.index', compact('alunos', 'search'));
}
```

My view:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ URL::to('alunos/busca') }}">
<input class="input-xxlarge" name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
<div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
        <input type="submit" class="btn" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
</div> 
<div class="divPagination">
   {{ $alunos->links() }}
</div>
```

I need help..

Sorry my English

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is the next one:

1. Copy and paste this form wherever you want it:

   ```
   {{Form::open(array('url' => 'alunos/busca','method' => 'get'))}}
   {{Form::text('q', null , array('placeholder' => 'Search...','class' => 'input-xxlarge'))}}
   {{Form::submit('SEARCH',array('class' => 'btn','id' => 'submit'))}}
   {{Form::close()}}
   ```
2. In `routes.php` :

   ```
   Route::get('alunos/busca', function() {
      $search = Input::get('q');
      $alunos = Aluno::where('curso', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->paginate(15);
      return View::make('alunos.index')
       ->with('alunos', $alunos);
   });
   ```
3. Now, in your view `app/views/alunos/index.blade.php` :

   ```
   @if(!$alunos->isEmpty())
      @foreach($alunos as $aluno)
         {{$aluno->subject}}
      @endforeach

    {{$alunos->links()}}

   @else
      <h1> No results </h1>
   @endif
   ```
4. Change it as you wish and enjoy

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when you click on the next page it has no memory of the search param you just entered, essentially `$q = null;` which will cause the error.

Comment: Ok.. you have any solutions?

Comment: Pass $q back to your view and check if it exists, set the input value back to the value.
`<?php $q = isset($q) ?: null;?>`
`<input name="q" value="{{{$q}}}">`